# Ожидание запроса HttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient

Умею пользовать HttpClient, хотел узнать есть ли возможность как в сокете ожидать ответа, тобишь клиент ждет пока сервер ему что нибудь не вышлет, после он обрабатывает данные и опять ждет.

Реально ли сделать такое через HttpClient и как?

Comment: думаю http не для этого предназначен :)

Comment: И чо, ServerSocket использовать?

Comment: `HTTP` протокол не предусматривает поддержания соединения. Да, использовать сокеты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для данной задачи нужно использовать ServerSocket